# cant achieve customised pagination in yii

Tags: php, yii, pagination

Here I go I need a customised pagination in yii as i am not using any of the widgets(which provides pagination feature) therefore i have code it but then i am unable to figure out as to why pagination is not been displayed

this is my controller action

```
        $db1 = Member::model()->cat();
        $arr1 = CJSON::encode($db1);        
        $criteria=new CDbCriteria;
        $criteria->with=array('fcategorys ','member ');
        $criteria->together=true;
        $criteria->select=array('name','cid');
        $criteria->condition="category=cid";
        $criteria->group=array('cid','name');
        $pages = new CPagination(Categorys::model() -> count($criteria));
// Set Page Limit

$pages -> pageSize = 2;
$pages -> applyLimit($criteria);
$this->render('paginationtrial',array('arr1'=>$arr1,'pages'=>$pages

    ));
```

view paginationtrial

```
$("#dispcat").html('');
    $.each(<?php echo $arr1; ?>, function (i, item) {

     $("#dispcat").append('<div class="product1"><div class="title"><a href="<?php echo Yii::app()->request-    >baseUrl;?>/index.php/product/productsincategory/id/' +  item.cid + '">>>' + item.name + '( ' +  item.prodincat + ')</a></div></div>');

    });


//});
$("#dispcat").fadeIn(2000);


});
```

```
</div>
<?php $this->widget('CLinkPager', array('pages' => $pages,
)) ?>
```

I don't get the pagination display for the above results

browser renders  the error stating

```
**Relation "fcategorys " is not defined in active record class "Categorys".**
```

Please HELP let me know  where am i going wrong

Comment: Could you add the code for `Categorys` `relations()` method?

Comment: I dont have any relations for it                              public function relations()
 {
  return array(
  );
 }

Comment: Hence the error. Add the required relations `fcategorys` and `member` or remove `$criteria->with....`